# Auto reload Nginx on certboot renew success?

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

Every three months, my Let's Encrypt certificate expires, and my customers get an invalid https certificate.

So I recently placed the following cron task :

```
@weekly certbot renew --quiet && service nginx reload
```

From my understanding, when `certbot renew` successfully update the certificate, it returns a success state (exit(0)), so the `&&` is followed, and so nginx is reloaded.

Yes but it doesn't work. I recently had my server showing again an expired certificate, so I certainly misunderstood something, and/or my cron task is not good.

Could you show me the path please? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

better approach is use `--renew-hook` which can call script. Also `--no-self-upgrade` is good option for automatic renew, this option prevent updates during renewal which can broke somethig

cron record can be

```
certbot renew --quiet --no-self-upgrade --renew-hook /path/to/hook.sh
```

`hook.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
nginx -t -q && nginx -s reload
exit 0
```

This script is called only when renew action happens and not every week

full explanation is in man page or [in documentation](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#certbot-command-line-options)

Comment: `--renew-hook` flag has been deprecated in recent versions of certbot. You should move your renew script into `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy/01-reload-nginx` - see https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2017/01/01/lets-encrypt-reload-nginx-after-renewing-certificates/ for more details.

Comment: Documentation for the renewal hooks: https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#renewing-certificates